# Richfaces: dropDownMenu action

Tags: java, jsf, components, richfaces

I understand, how to set action to rich:menuItem component, but can i somehow set action on rich:dropDownMenu? Parameter action cannot be set in rich:dropDownMenu component, only in dropDownMenus child rich:menuItem. Maybe there is another approach?

Action setting to rich:menuItem:

`<rich:menuItem submitMode="server" value="#{msg.someValue}" action="#{billdoc.list}">`

I need to execute some action #{billdoc.someAction}, when user clicks on dropDownMenu.

Answer (score 2):

If you are really sure you need this (it's rather strange), you can use `<rich:dropDownMenu onexpand="myFunction()"`, and define `myFunction` as:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="myFunction" action="#{billdoc.someAction}" />
```

Comment: Dropdownmenu hasn't onClick method?

Comment: it seems it doesn't have. But why not use onexpand?

Comment: I have menu which can be represented as:
Documents -> Bills, Contracts. When user clicks on Bills, he gets list with bill documents, when contracts, then contract documents. But when he clicks on Documents itself, he gets list with bills and contracts. Now i have Bills and Contracts as menuItems, but Documents as dropDownMenu.

Comment: Get it this way, if user clicks on Bills, then Bills got selected, and a `onchange` event got fired, isn't it? Then on `onchange` event you can call a function, which would get the selected item, and based on that show the appropriate thing. i.e. if selected item is Bills, show Bill documents, etc.. Hope this made the thing clear.

Comment: Not exactly. dropDownMenu doesn't have onchange property.